# How Does Wireguard Peer Communication Work?

Tags: linux, vpn, pfsense, wireguard, self-hosting

I have wireguard setup in a VPS to get around CGNAT. My pfSense router is connected to it as a peer, and then I have my phone as a peer to the VPS. This is because I can't add it in pfSense without an endpoint.

This works, and I'm even able to use my local DNS lookups from my phone...but is it working because it's "misconfigured"? Just want to make sure that this is a valid wireguard setup and I can recreate it later if necessary. Here's more details

VPS

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <private-key>
DNS = 192.168.1.100

[Peer]
PublicKey = <pfsense>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.100/32, 10.1.0.0/24, 192.168.33.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = <iphone>
AllowedIPs = 10.1.0.0/24
```

pfSense then has a static tunnel (aka "dynamic endpoint" is unchecked) connected to the VPS address and `AllowedIPs` is set to the entire `10.1.0.0/24` network (this is why I think everything works, it's allowing any IP on the network...but why doesn't it have to be explicit?)

My phone is the same as pfSense, except it also allows for `192.168.33.0/24` and has the same DNS as the VPS.

I guess it looks like this

```
        VPS
     |      |
pfSense -- phone
```

but I expected that without pfSense having my phone as a peer, it would have been setup as

```
        VPS
     |      |
pfSense    phone
```

and communication between `pfSense` and `phone` is blocked because of the missing peer.

My guess is that wireguard allows communication from `phone <-> VPS <-> pfSense` because `pfSense` is configured to allow for the entire network.

Is this right? Just want to make sure that if I had to set this up again, say I used a VM instead of pfSense, I could recreate my configuration and everything would work again.